# How to add new colum with ascending values depending on the positions of specific values in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
P_ID  W_ID
 1     2
 1     8
 1     4
 1     8
 2     2
 2     8
 3     6
 3     8
 3     2
 3     8
 3     2
 3     4
```

I want to add a new column (NEW_ID). For each person it should start with 1 up to the first observation, which has the value W_ID == 8 (For this observation NEW_ID should as well equal 1). For the first observation afterwards and up to the next observation, which has the value W_ID == 8, NEW_ID should equal 2. And then so on.

It should look like this:

```
NEW_ID  P_ID  W_ID
   1     1     2
   1     1     8
   2     1     4
   2     1     8
   1     2     2
   1     2     8
   1     3     6
   1     3     8
   2     3     2
   2     3     8
   3     3     2
   3     3     4
```

This is my code so far:

```
new_dataframe <- old_dataframe %>%
  group_by(P_ID) %>%
  mutate(NEW_ID = cumsum(lag(W_ID == 8, default = FALSE)) + 1)
```

I can not be sure, if the code is working, since the dataframe is too big to check. Do you think it is a good way to use `cumsum()`?

Comment: You need to include an example data